# Realm copy all objects

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Is it possible to copy all objects from Realm when retrieving them like this?

```
let realm = try Realm()
let pendingPhotos = realm.objects(PendingPhoto)
```

Right now, I am recreating all the objects again by looping through all the pending photos and creating another Realm object.

Comment: What do you mean by "copy all objects from Realm"? Can you provide an example of what you've tried, and what result you're looking for?

Comment: I mean like making a copy of an object. The equivalent would be .copy in obj-c in the past

Comment: Do you want the copy to be an object that's stored in the Realm, or an unmanaged object?

Answer (score 3):

You can create **shallow detached** copies of your objects by using `init(value: _)`.

You can create **shallow managed** copies of your objects by using `Realm.create(: _, value: _, update: _)`, but only if the last argument is passed as `false`.

You can apply both to lists by using map:

```
let copies = pendingPhotos.map { PendingPhoto(value: $0) }
```

**Shallow** copies means that the relationships of objects retrieved in that way aren't deeply copied. So on all relations you will see the same object instances attached as on your original objects.